# icq new bot api ограничить область работы бота

Tags: python, бот, icq

Есть код:

```
def message_start(bot,event):
    bot.send_text(chat_id=event.from_chat, text = START_MESSAGE)
    
def start_meeting(bot):
    bot.dispatcher.add_handler(StartCommandHandler(callback=message_start))
```

При использовании команды `/start` он отправляет сообщение пользователю. Т.к. бот работает и с чатами, он реагирует и в них. Например в aiogram для телеграмм есть фильтры позволяющие строго ограничить область работы бота. Как сделать на ICQ NEW Bot API подобное?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил так:

```
if event.data['chat']['chatId'] != '6*******7@chat.agent':
    bot.send_text(chat_id=event.from_chat, text = START_MESSAGE)
```

Я нагло проверяю от куда пришла команда, и если это мой чат, то проверка не дает вывести результат, но считаю сие творение лютым костылем, если кто знает решение получше, помогите.